# Is there any embeddable API for OpenAuth or any other social network auth method?

Tags: c, facebook-graph-api, twitter, google-api

I want my embedded device, which doesn't run a full operating system but has a TCPIP stack with optional SSL, to be able to login on social networks (Twitter and Facebook but if there is a generalized answer that would be better) to share statuses/tweets/whatever pertaining to the device itself.

I got my account registered as a developer on FB and started studying their API.
Apart being bored by all the AJAX and PHP which aren't really my thing, I got the idea there is NO WAY an embedded device can login into such a service unless it is able to run a heavy javascript, essentially ruling out all those devices lacking a full operating system.

So what I'm looking for is any information pertaining how to use social networks from an embedded device. Any 3rd party API, bridge site, or whatever is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that OAuth could be used for it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

There is util, which allow use OAuth from bash script:

https://github.com/livibetter/bash-oauth

You can try rewrite it from Twitter and bash to Facebook and your platform.

Comment: Unless I'm badly mistaken, the oauth has to be "passed" via a web interface (at least that was how it was done in the Facebook tutorial).

I don't have a web client on my device, I need a programmatic API. Something invokable by C code.

You also cited bash, but as I said I don't have an operating system, so no bash at all.

Comment: You are right, I have not noticed that command line access require KEY and SECRET, whitch cannot common user get from Twitter/Facebook.